# Impact of changing the fine structure constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

During my Nuclear and Particle Physics lecture today, the instructor mentioned something about the fine structure constant, $\alpha_e$, and how it impacts the stability of particles.

He showed us a plot of mass excess versus atomic number, using this equation: $$\text{mass excess} = \left(M_n - a_v + \dfrac{a_s}{A^{1/3}} + \dfrac{a_a}{4}\right)A - \left(a_a+(M_n-M_p-m_e)\right)Z + \left(\dfrac{a_a}{A} + \dfrac{a_c}{A_{1/3}}\right)Z^2 + \dfrac{a_p}{A^{1/2}} - A$$
Where all of the constants are masses or coefficients from the SEMF. The plot is an upward facing parabola for a choice of $A$. The one shown in the image below is for $A=111$.

The mimimum of the plot is the most stable value of $Z$ for the given $A$, and the instructor mentioned that for this, the most stable value of $Z$ is $48$.

Here's the part I don't understand. He mentioned that changing $\alpha_e$ by only $10\%$ would change the minimum of that plot to occur at $47$ instead of $48$.

I do not see $\alpha_e$ anywhere in the above equation, and the constants do not appear to depend on $\alpha_e$. So how did he get that number, and how does he know that the fine structure constant would change the most stable $Z$ for the given $A$?

I asked him and he smirked, saying I should try to figure it out on my own. I can't seem to, though.

Here is the aforementioned graph:

[image]

Comment: Do you understand the meaning for the $a$ co-efficients you've written down? In particular, what is $a_c$?

Comment: @jacob1729 Somewhat. I know that they are coefficients for an estimate of the binding energy. $a_c$ is the coefficient for the coulomb term - protons in the nucleus will repel each other thus reduce the binding energy. Its value doesn't remind me of $\alpha_e$, and I can see a potential relationship between the two. I am not sure what it is, though.